# Sidekiq perform_at specified datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sidekiq

I'm using the SideKiq Ruby gem and I want to use

`perform_at`

From the wiki I read that I can use

`perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1)`

...Is there a way to use

`perform at`

on a specific datetime? For example, if I save a variable

`datetime = 2014/Apr/16 22:30`

could I just write something like

`perform_at(datetime, do_something)`

Comment: "Could I just write something like" - yes, you can. `datetime = Date.today` or `datetime = Time.now`.

Comment: @DamienRoche I have a form that collects a datetime in the format datetime = `2014-12-30 20:01:00` . So `perform_at(datetime, do_something)` would work in that instance?

Comment: See here for what the method expects: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/Worker/ClassMethods:perform_in. `perform_at` will call `to_f` on the datetime argument. If your datetime returns a timestamp, then it will work. If not, you'll have to convert to a workable format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is `MessageWorker.perform_at(@message.date_time, @message.id)`

Answer (score 4):

For those who can't use perform at you could solve this using `set(wait_until: time)` like:

```
Message.set(wait_until: someTime).perform_later(args)
```

This will queue your message inside Sidekiq for your desired date-time.